# Bootstrap 4 not working with Bootstrap select

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I recently upgraded the following NuGet packages in my solution:

`bootstrap v3.3.7 -> bootstrap v4.1.1`
`bootstrap-select v1.13.0 -> bootstrap select v1.31.1`

And am noticing an issue with my selectable dropdowns...
[image: greyed-out dropdowns]

As you can see, these bootstrap select dropdowns are greyed out, and clicking on them doesn't allow me to view any options in the dropdowns.

Now, on `bootstrap v3.3.7' these bootstrap select dropdowns were fully functional
[image]

Also, this is the code I'm currently using to populate the dropdowns. Before this method is called, a callout to a web service is made to gather data to populate the dropdowns.

```
var getClientsSuccess = function (data) {
    $("#SeClientId").empty();
    $("#SeClientId").selectpicker("destroy");
    $("<option>").val("0").text("Select Client").appendTo("#SeClientId");
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $("<option>").val(value.org_uid).text(value.org_name).appendTo("#SeClientId");
    });
    $("#SeClientId").selectpicker({ liveSearch: true, showSubtext: true, size: 10 });
    $("#SeClientId").selectpicker("refresh");
};
```

So, what could have changed in bootstrap v4 that would have broken my bootstrap select functionality?

Comment: Can you provide documentation/links to the library you're using for searchable dropdowns?

Comment: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/